# Laravel return view show message

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-5.1, message

How can I show a message after I return a view in my Controller.

I am using Laravel 5.1.

```
 return view('pr.new', [
      'errorMessageDuration' => 'error too long',
      'route' => 'createPr',
      'type' => 'new',
 ]);
```

I tried to call the message like this:

```
  @if(session('errorMessageDuration'))
         <div class="alert alert-danger">
             <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
             {{ session('errorMessageDuration') }}
             {{ Input::get('title') }}
         </div>
  @endif
```

But it did not work, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use code Like This

```
@if(isset($errorMessageDuration))
         <div class="alert alert-danger">
             <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
             {{ $errorMessageDuration }}
             {{ Input::get('title') }}
         </div>
  @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Redirect`, then you need to use session like what you did,

**Controller**:

```
return redirect('dashboard')->with('errorMessageDuration', 'Error!');
```

**View**:

```
@if(empty(session('errorMessageDuration')))
         <div class="alert alert-danger">
             <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
             {{ session('errorMessageDuration') }}
             {{ Input::get('title') }}
         </div>
@endif
```

But if you pass the variables using `View` facade, then you should just like what Rakesh showed:

**Controller**:

```
 return view('pr.new', [
      'errorMessageDuration' => 'error too long',
      'route' => 'createPr',
      'type' => 'new',
 ]);
```

**View**:

```
@if(isset($errorMessageDuration))
         <div class="alert alert-danger">
             <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
             {{ $errorMessageDuration }}
             {{ Input::get('title') }}
         </div>
@endif
```